# Setting up path in PATH terraform

Tags: linux, bash, path, terraform, devops

on `echo $PATH` getting following output which i think is not complete 
output `:/snap/bin/terraform`
how to set it right, also if its right then I'm not able to use command `terraform init` getting following error

```
Command 'terraform' is available in '/snap/bin/terraform'
The command could not be located because '/snap/bin' is not included 
in the PATH environment variable. 
terraform: command not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't add the command in `$PATH`, it is enough to add its folder, like this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/snap/bin
```

you can update `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.profile` or others to save this change, depend on which shell you use.